# Display all the service name in a different table and the pictures below it

Tags: php, html, mysql, image, while-loop

I want to display all the Services that is in a table called 'services' and below it is the pictures/photos of that service which is in the other table called 'gallery'.

Database:

services: id, serviceName, serviceDesc
gallery: id, pictureImage, pictureName, pictureDesc

This is what I am trying to achieve,

Service 1
(picture1) (picture2) (picture3)

Service 2
(picture4) (picture5) (picture6)

Service 3
(picture7) (picture8)
This is my code:

```
            $query1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM gallery") OR die("Error: ".mysqli_error($conn));
            $query2 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM services") OR die("Error: ".mysqli_error($conn));
            while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)){
              echo"<p>".$row2['serviceName']."</p>";
            while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)){
              echo"
              <div class='col-md-3'>
                <div class='galleryCard'>
                  <a href='image/$row1[pictureImage]'><img class='img img-responsive' src='image/".$row1['pictureImage']."' width='100%'></a>
                  <p class='galleryText'>".$row1['pictureDesc']."</p>
                </div>
              </div>";
            }
          }
```

This is for my school projects and I'm so sorry for my bad english and messy question, I hope you guys understand it. Thank you!

Comment: first you need to link images to services so you can identify the service of the images, only by then you can do such grouping

Comment: Can you code it for me? hehe. I already tried to link and group it but I just really don't know how to do it properly. And pictureName is the name of that Service so i have already tried using sql joins WHERE pictureName = serviceName.

Comment: Well, since you're a newbie aroundhere, let me give you a heads up. It's considered really bad to ask someone do the coding for you. This is for helping. Skipping that, you can add another column to gallery table with the name service_id (make it as the same type of the table service's id column) and put the id of the service of each image. Then you can use joins if you want.

Comment: Omgg. I got it :) Thank yoou so much and I'm really sorry1

Comment: You can cut your 2 connection/query calls down to one by joining those tables. If you're ever interested to learn something new and challenging, have a look at the following tutorial, http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/ - It's a good place to learn. There's a lot of good stuff on that site and you will definitely benefit from it, should you want to go further into working with databases. @Mhtyr

Comment: I agree with @FunkFortyNiner on using 1 query by joining those as long as you have **small sets of data** in them and you optimize your record output by using actual column names instead of `*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another column to table `gallery` with the name `service_id` (make it as the same type of the table `service`'s `id` column) and put the id of the service of each image. Then change your code as below to make the magic work

```
$query1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM services") OR die("Error: ".mysqli_error($conn));
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)){
    echo"<p>".$row2['serviceName']."</p>";
    //choose only the images belonging to the service
    $query2 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE `service_id`=".$row1['id']) OR die("Error: ".mysqli_error($conn));

    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)){
        echo"
          <div class='col-md-3'>
            <div class='galleryCard'>
              <a href='image/".$row1['pictureImage']."'><img class='img img-responsive' src='image/".$row1['pictureImage']."' width='100%'></a>
              <p class='galleryText'>".$row1['pictureDesc']."</p>
            </div>
          </div>";
    }
}
```